# upload a file using angular, express and mongodb's gridfs

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, express, gridfs

I am new to these technologies and hence have limited knowledge on how to upload a file. During my research, I have seen ngUpload and other javascript/directive based solutions. However, I am trying the following and not sure what else I am missing to complete it.

I am trying to upload file after creating a blog using angular-express-blog application. I have the following code

In view.jade

```
fieldset
            h5 Add Media
            form(name='theForm', enctype="multipart/form-data")
              .clearfix
                label Document Name
                .input: input(ng-model='form.docName', name='docName', type='text')
              .clearfix
                label File
                .input: input(ng-model='form.file', type="file", name="file")
              .actions
              button(ng-click="uploadFiles('/page3files')") Upload Files
```

the controller, I do need to return to the uploadfile page hence, I am passing in /page3files.

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function( path ) {
        //alert("upload files clikced");
        $http.post('/api/uploadFile', $scope.form).
           success(function(data) {
               $scope.form.docName='';
               $scope.form.file='';
               $location.path(path);
           });
    };
```

In the express routes file

```
exports.uploadFile = function (req, res) {
      console.log("doc name: " + req.body.docName);
      console.log("file name: " + req.body.file.name);
      console.log("file path: " + req.body.file.path);
      res.json(true);
};
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an exception at req.body.file.name saying cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Melroy

Answer (score 4):

for the $http.post() to be able to upload files you need to set some configurations.
headers : {'Content-Type': undefined},
transformRequest: angular.identity

You can use the simple/lightweight [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) directive that takes care of that for you.
It supports drag&drop, file progress and file upload for non-HTML5 browsers with FileAPI flash shim.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var $file = $files[i];
      $upload.upload({
        url: 'my/upload/url',
        file: $file,
        progress: function(e){}
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      }); 
    }
  }
}];
```

There are more info on the [README](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/master/README.md) page and there is a [Demo page](http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/)

Comment: make sure you add `app.use(express.multipart())` to express config!

Comment: @david_adler that's throwing: `Error: Most middleware (like multipart) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.`

Answer (score 1):

You can send file data with `FormData` object. For Example:

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Upload Video</legend>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
    <input type="button" ng-click="uploadVideo()" value="Upload">
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
$scope.uploadVideo = function () {
    var photo = document.getElementById("photo");
    var file = photo.files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();  //Create FormData object
    fd.append('file', file);

    $http.post('/uploadVideo', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).success(function (data) {
            // Do your work
        });
 };
```